# Type NSDecimalNumber in swift 3 with sdk paypal

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, swift3

When I am creating the item to send to paypal I do the following

```
let ammountRequest: String = txtAmmount.text!
let item = PayPalItem(name: "shop things", withQuantity: 1, withPrice: NSDecimalNumber(string: ammountRequest), withCurrency: "EUR", withSku: "Create Balance")

let items = [item]
let subtotal = PayPalItem.totalPrice(forItems: items)
```

If the "ammountRequest" equals 11.12 for example, on the page to pay will appear the 11 instead of the 11.12 as
Can I do to appear the decimal places since they are being removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably not dealing well with localization. `NSDecimalNumber(string: ammountRequest)` is trying to parse the string using the current locale. Therefore you have to be sure that the string contains `,` (comma) or `.` (point) as the decimal separator depending on the current locale.

The discussion in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdecimalnumber/1578296-decimalnumberwithstring?language=objc#discussion) describes the accepted values depending on locale.

One way to deal with this is to replace all possible decimal separators (`.` and `,`) with `.` and then use English locale (ideally the POSIX locale):

```
let amountString = "11.12"
let normalizedAmountString = amountString.replacingOccurrences(of: "[,.]", with: ".", options: .regularExpression)

let posixLocale = Locale(identifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let amount = NSDecimalNumber(string: normalizedAmountString, locale: posixLocale)
print(amount)
```

Note that most of the times `NSDecimalNumber` can deal with both `.` and `,`. The problems appear when `.` or `,` is a grouping separator in the current locale.

PS: You should use `Decimal` instead of `NSDecimalNumber` in Swift code.

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you so much